# Get all values from a Column in SQLite and return as a list

Tags: android, list, sqlite, android-recyclerview

I am trying to populate a RecyclerView with the data in each column.

I want to retrieve all of the values under a column and return it as a List dynamically.

What is the best way to go about this?

Attached is a sample image of the data:

[image]

There is a list of tables I am showing in the app, then the user should be able to click on a table name and see a RecyclerView of all of the values under each column with swipeable tabs.

For the image above, the user should see a recyclerview of CreateDate, then swipe over and see a recyclerview of CreatedByTablet, etc.

The problem I am encountering is how to return all of the values in a column, **dynamically**. I am not that familiar with SQL so how would I go about accomplishing this? And how would the method know to return a `List<String>` or a `List<Integer>`?

Here is some code I wrote to attempt this:

```
// Get all table names
public List<String> getAllTableNames() {

    List<String> tableNames = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        String query = "SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'";
        SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DB_PATH + DB_NAME, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

        // Iterate
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
                tableNames.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name")));
                cursor.moveToNext();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return tableNames;
}

// Get all names of columns inside a table
public List<String> getAllColumnNames(String tableName) {

    List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + tableName;
        SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DB_PATH + DB_NAME, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null, null);
        String[] columnNames = cursor.getColumnNames();
        names = Arrays.asList(columnNames);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return names;
}

public int getColumnType(String tableName, String columnName) {

    String[] args = { columnName };

    try {
        int type;
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + tableName;
        SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DB_PATH + DB_NAME, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, args);
        Log.d(TAG, "Column Index: " + String.valueOf(cursor.getColumnIndex(columnName)));
        type = cursor.getType(cursor.getColumnIndex(columnName));
        return type;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return 0;
}

public List getAllRows(String tableName, String columnName, int type) {

    Log.d(TAG, "Getting all rows");
    switch (type) {
        case 1:
            List<Integer> integerList = createIntegerList(tableName, columnName);
            return integerList;
        case 3:
            List<String> stringList = createStringList(tableName, columnName);
            return stringList;
    }

    return null;
}

private List<Integer> createIntegerList(String tableName, String columnName) {

    List<Integer> integerList = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + tableName;
        SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DB_PATH + DB_NAME, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
                int number = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(columnName));
                integerList.add(number);
                cursor.moveToNext();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return integerList;
}

private List<String> createStringList(String tableName, String columnName) {

    List<String> integerList = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + tableName;
        SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DB_PATH + DB_NAME, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
                String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(columnName));
                integerList.add(name);
                cursor.moveToNext();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return integerList;
}
```

**How can I return a list of integer or string (depending of column data type) of all the values in a column inside a table in Sqlite android?**

Comment: Are you looking to have `ArrayList<Object>` as the return type of your method, and then use `instanceof` to determine what you get after calling the method?

Comment: Precisely I was thinking along those lines but wouldn't there be casting issues? Also what SQL command method allows you to retrieve all the values in a column?

Comment: You would need to have a separate case for each database field in your method that queries the database.  Honestly, I think it's best to keep it as you have it now, and just call the appropriate method when needed, if you can make it work like that.

Comment: For some reason it's not getting all the values under each column with the code above what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which specific method is having an issue?

Comment: For starters getColumnType always shows 1 for the column index. And I can't seem to find a good tutorial to show me how to iterate over the values in each column

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77751/discussion-between-daniel-nugent-and-andyroid).